# Create fullCalendar calendar event on submitting the form in bootstrap modal window

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, twitter-bootstrap, fullcalendar

I've a fullCalendar implementation and am trying to create a bootstrap modal window on clicking anywhere on the calendar and then saving the calendar entry on "submitting" the form in the modal window.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var calendar = $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
    //header and other values
    select: function(start, end, allDay) {
        var endtime = $.fullCalendar.formatDate(end,'h:mm tt');
    var starttime = $.fullCalendar.formatDate(start,'ddd, MMM d, h:mm tt');
    var mywhen = starttime + ' - ' + endtime;
        $('#createEventModal #when').text(mywhen);
        $('#createEventModal').modal('show');
     },
    //other functions
  });
```

Here's the HTML for modal screen:

```
<div id="createEventModal" class="modal hide" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel1" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">x</button>
        <h3 id="myModalLabel1">Create Appointment</h3>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-body">
    <form id="createAppointmentForm" class="form-horizontal">
        <div class="control-group">
            <label class="control-label" for="inputPatient">Patient:</label>
            <div class="controls">
                <input type="text" name="patientName" id="patientName" tyle="margin: 0 auto;" data-provide="typeahead" data-items="4" data-source="[&quot;Value 1&quot;,&quot;Value 2&quot;,&quot;Value 3&quot;]">
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="control-group">
            <label class="control-label" for="when">When:</label>
            <div class="controls controls-row" id="when" style="margin-top:5px;">
            </div>
        </div>
    </form>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-footer">
        <button class="btn" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">Cancel</button>
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" id="submitButton">Save</button>
    </div>
</div>
```

In another javascript file that's called within the main HTML, I've the following:

```
$('#submitButton').on('click', function(e){
    // We don't want this to act as a link so cancel the link action
    e.preventDefault();

    // Find form and submit it
    $('#createAppointmentForm').submit();
  });

$('#createAppointmentForm').on('submit', function(){
    alert("form submitted");
    $("#createEventModal").modal('hide');
    $calendar.fullCalendar('renderEvent',
        {
            title: $('#patientName').val();,
            start: start,
            end: end,
            allDay: allDay
        },
        true
    );
```

This is not working. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You need to preserve the `start`, `end` and `allDay` parameters from the `select` function.

For example, store them in hidden inputs in the dialog form:

```
        <div class="controls">
            <input type="text" name="patientName" id="patientName" tyle="margin: 0 auto;" data-provide="typeahead" data-items="4" data-source="[&quot;Value 1&quot;,&quot;Value 2&quot;,&quot;Value 3&quot;]">
              <input type="hidden" id="apptStartTime"/>
              <input type="hidden" id="apptEndTime"/>
              <input type="hidden" id="apptAllDay" />
        </div>
```

And in the `select` function of fullcalendar set the values of the hidden fields:

```
  select: function(start, end, allDay) {
      endtime = $.fullCalendar.formatDate(end,'h:mm tt');
      starttime = $.fullCalendar.formatDate(start,'ddd, MMM d, h:mm tt');
      var mywhen = starttime + ' - ' + endtime;
      $('#createEventModal #apptStartTime').val(start);
      $('#createEventModal #apptEndTime').val(end);
      $('#createEventModal #apptAllDay').val(allDay);
      $('#createEventModal #when').text(mywhen);
      $('#createEventModal').modal('show');
   }
```

And then you can use the values from these fields in the `submit`:

```
function doSubmit(){
    alert("form submitted");
    $("#createEventModal").modal('hide');

    $("#calendar").fullCalendar('renderEvent',
    {
        title: $('#patientName').val(),
        start: new Date($('#apptStartTime').val()),
        end: new Date($('#apptEndTime').val()),
        allDay: ($('#apptAllDay').val() == "true"),
    },
    true);
}
```

[Fiddle here with a demo](http://jsfiddle.net/mccannf/AzmJv/16/).