# Modal window wont display from Javascript call

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, fullcalendar, typeerror

Im trying to pop up a form from the fullcalender.js plugin. I have the form in a bootstrap modal div and am trying to pop it up, fill it out and commit details to database etc.

The problem is that the modal will not display, i have read through SO  [links such as this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14207318/create-fullcalendar-calendar-event-on-submitting-the-form-in-bootstrap-modal-win) and have adapted code from 
    [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mccannf/AzmJv/16/) i have gone as far as copy/pasting that fiddle which works there but not for me, is there an issue because mine is a .jsp page or am i missing .js files.

I have all the bootstrap and fullcallender .js files included, any advice ?

```
  $('#myModal').modal('show');
```

This should work right ? but it dosen't seem to

EDIT

```
 <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script>       
    <script>window.jQuery || document.write('<script src="js/jquery.min.js"><\/script>');</script>

    <!-- Include all compiled plugins (below), or include individual files as needed -->
    <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/moment.min.js"></script>       
    <script src="js/fullcalendar.min.js"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript">

        $(document).ready(function () {

            var calendar = $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
                header: {
                   ...etc
                },                  
                defaultView: 'agendaWeek',
                editable: true,
                selectable: true,
                selectHelper: true,
                height: 846,
                select: function (start, end, allDay) {
                    endtime = $.fullCalendar.formatDate(end, 'h:mm tt');
                    starttime = $.fullCalendar.formatDate(start, 'ddd, MMM d, h:mm tt');
                    var mywhen = starttime + ' - ' + endtime;
                    $('#createEventModal #apptStartTime').val(start);
                    $('#createEventModal #apptEndTime').val(end);
                    $('#createEventModal #apptAllDay').val(allDay);
                    $('#createEventModal #when').text(mywhen);
                    $('#createEventModal').modal('show');
                }
            });
```

EDIT

my error is an **Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function**

on this line

```
 endtime = $.fullCalendar.formatDate(end, 'h:mm tt');
```

Comment: We will need more code than this to tell if you're missîg something... And an error message would help too.

Comment: `jsp`???.. that is not javascript

Comment: There is no error message from the IDE , it complains about nothing anyway, and yes @BrettCaswell jsp is not javascript but a little javascript running from a jsp page is what then ?

Comment: @Aaron JSP is a javaserver page, that is running on server that returns a response in the form of html+javascript.

Comment: @RomanC yes and im trying to pop up a form locally with javascript and fill it with details that will be processed server side with java, hence the Javaserver page , but thats not my question

Comment: @Aaron, you right.. that shouldn't be an issue. I mistakenly thought you were implying that you were doing a script src reference to the jsp page. At any rate, check for the error messages in your browser, not the IDE. Do F12 (usually) to invoke the developer tools.. refresh the page. and see if there are any errors on page load for the scripts.

Answer (score 0):

Solved :)

I had been methods that were updated in the newer version of fullcalender.js. i was using this,

```
 endtime = $.fullCalendar.formatDate(end, 'h:mm tt');
 starttime = $.fullCalendar.formatDate(start, 'ddd, MMM d, h:mm tt');
```

When i should have been using this,

```
 starttime = moment(start).format('ddd, MMM do, h:mma ');
 endtime = moment(end).format('ddd, MMM do, h:mma ');
```

Thanks for your help and hope this helps someone else.