# Adding an Event in jQuery Full Calendar with Bootstrap Modal with PHP

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, fullcalendar

I want to enter a Calendar Event details using Bootstrap modal... But that modal is not invoking, when I click on date of a Calendar....

I google for it, it shows me the following code... But it won't work for me...

```
select: function(start, end, allDay)
{
     $('#myModal').modal('show');                         
},
```

I followed the following URL [Fullcalendar (Arshaw) - Adding an event with modal window](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40102446/fullcalendar-arshaw-adding-an-event-with-modal-window)

**CalendarView**

**Calling Modal from Calendar**

```
<head>
    var calendar = $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
            editable:true,
            header:{
                left:'prev,next today',
                center:'title',
                right:'month,agendaWeek,agendaDay'
            },
            events:'load',
            selectable:true,

            select: function(start, end, allDay)
            {
                 $('#myModal').modal('show');                         
             },
</head>
```

**Modal to call**

```
   <div id="calendar">
    <div class="modal fade" id="myModal">
      <div class="modal-dialog">
      <div class="modal-content">

      <!-- Modal Header -->
        <div class="modal-header">
          <h4 class="modal-title">Modal Heading</h4>
          <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times; 
          </button>
        </div>


      <!-- Modal body -->
        <div class="modal-body">
          Modal body..
        </div>

         <!-- Modal footer -->
        <div class="modal-footer">
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        </div>
```

Comment: did you just forget the `<script>` tags?

Answer (score 1):

You should enclose your scripts on a `<script>` tag:

```
<head>
    <script>
        var calendar = $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
            editable:true,
            header:{
                left:'prev,next today',
                center:'title',
                right:'month,agendaWeek,agendaDay'
            },
            events:'load',
            selectable:true,
            select: function(start, end, allDay)
            {
                $('#myModal').modal('show');                         
            },
    </script>
</head>
```

Comment: Thank you for reply...I enclosed in<script> tag only

Answer (score 0):

Instead of 'select', try using 'dateClick' event when you click on an empty date cell, or 'eventClick' when you click on an event -perhaps you'd like to edit it.

Comment: dateClick   : function(start, end, allDay)
                 {
                 $('#myModal').modal('show');                         
           },     This solution not worked for me....